# Why is a filesystem created with mkfs not available immediately

Tags: linux, filesystems

Why are file systems created with `mkfs` not immediately available after creation?

The following command line probably best describes what I'm seeing:

```
/sbin/mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc && lsblk -o uuid --noheadings /dev/sdc
```

First I'm creating an ext4 filesystem on `/dev/sdc` and then I'm trying to immediately show the UUID of that filesystem.

This is the corresponding output of those commands:

```
mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sdc contains a ext4 file system
        created on Wed Oct  5 00:40:08 2022
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
Discarding device blocks: done
Creating filesystem with 268435456 4k blocks and 67108864 inodes
Filesystem UUID: d54169aa-faab-49b5-b0fd-fdf98b603df0
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968,
        102400000, 214990848

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

434269b5-59e4-4fd0-95f0-376090e0e0a9
```

You'll notice that "Filesystem UUID" from the `mkfs.ext4` output does not match the output of `lsblk` shown at the end of the output.

However, if I rerun `lsblk -o uuid --noheadings /dev/sdc` a little bit later, I get:

```
d54169aa-faab-49b5-b0fd-fdf98b603df0
```

And that does match the `mkfs.ext4` output. Why the delay?

Answer (score 1):

If mkfs.ext4 returns without error, it can be used, including by file system UUID. `mount UUID=434269b5-59e4-4fd0-95f0-376090e0e0a9 /mnt`  or whatever, and put it in fstab if you are happy.

On Linux, some distros decided a nice hardware experience means some user space programs meddle in the process. Namely udev (hardware events system) and blkid (block device probing functions). Per man lsblk:

> Note that lsblk might be executed in time when udev does not have all
> information about recently added or
> modified devices yet. In this case it is recommended to use udevadm settle before lsblk to synchronize with
> udev.

A user space program created a file system, and a user space program figured out the resulting UUID, but they have no direct integration. Also lsblk has a cache. Resulting in short delays. And stale data from any previous file system, note that you were re-creating over an existing ext4 without something like a wipefs command.

Mounting it directly results in a low level blkid probe same as the command `blkid --uuid d54169aa-faab-49b5-b0fd-fdf98b603df0`  which by default will scan all block devices to find unknown volumes.